# d3-ng2-service has no exported member ThresholdArraygenerator

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, d3.js

I am getting this error:

> node_modules/d3-ng2-service/src/bundle-d3"' has no exported member 'ThresholdArrayGenerator'

while creating build in angular 5 with node -v10.

`ng serve` also gives the same error.